# Unexpected result in DAX SUMX over GROUPBY

Tags: powerbi, dax

The result of my DAX measure is not behaving as expected.

The following is the DAX expression:

```
myMeasure=SUMX(GROUPBY(myTable,myTable[id],"v1",COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(),myTable[value])),[v1])
```

The table myTable has the following columns: [date],[id],[value]
The purpose of this measure is to first do an summary for each [id] (in this case a simple count of elements for each [id]) and then SUMX across the summaries for the different [id].

Given a basic example in which I just select the [date] in March 2019, the following is a matrix visual with the results:

[image]

There is only one value for [id] selected by the filters in the page (20026) and the values for [date] are filtered in the page to be in March 2019.

The result of the measure for each [date]x[id] pair is 1.
However, the total for all dates is showing a 5 which doesn't seem to make sense.
Given the data I would expect to see a total of 31.

The same concept is working as expected (I get 31 in the grand total) if I write it using SUMMARIZE:

```
myMeasure=SUMX(SUMMARIZE(myTable,myTable[id]),COUNT(myTable[value]))
```

What is wrong with the first version?

Comment: I can't reproduce the subtotal you show. Can you provide a dataset that does?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the data as is and I haven't been able to quickly put together a dataset to reproduce. At the moment I can move on using the second expression but I would have thought both expression have to arrive to the same total of 31. I cannot think of a reason why getting 1 each day on the first case the total would be 5 and not 31.

Comment: I can't think of a reason either, but if you can provide a way to reproduce the problem, I'm interested in taking another look.